# A white input bar appear when typing on keyboard while play game

Tags: macos, text-input

I have a problem everytime I play a game on my Mac, and try to use keyboard's alphabet characters, a white input bar appear on the bottom of the screen (and the character go there instead of to the game). What is it and how can I turn it off? Thank you very much

It like this

[image]

Comment: could you provide a screenshot (press `cmd` + `shift` + `4` for making screenshots)?

Comment: Hi, thank for replying. I edited the question with a screenshot

Comment: Do you have any clue if this bar is from the game or any other software? What happens if you press enter?

Comment: I have no idea, It appears on every game I play. Nothing happens when I press enter

Comment: It seems like it is some other app you installed. If you press `cmd`+`tab` will you go back to the game?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I use foreign keyboard. As soon as I switch the keyboard input back to "U.S" the input bar disappears. And it seems like it's associated with Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a third party app that is listening for keyboard hits, possibly a key combination.

Try doing the Command+Option+Esc combo and see what apps are running. Better yet, type in the box so that is the active app and see if one of them is automatically highlighted. In my screenshot, you can see that I was using google chrome at the time I hit the key combo.

[image: Force Quit to find app]

Force Quit the offending app and delete or check out their forums for more information.